# JNI: Association between Java and C++ classes

Tags: android, java-native-interface

Since C++ classes aren't directly accessibly from Java, I have a Java wrapper  with native functions `instantiate` (called from Java constructor) and `release` (called from Java `finalize` method).

That would be quite straightforward, if not for one nuisance. Instead of keeping one instance of C++, I find it logical to have separate instances of C++ classes for each instance of the Java class. To accomplish that I keep a pointer to C++ instance in Java object, stored as long.

This is how it effectively looks like:

Java:

```
class MyClassWrapper {
    @Keep private long jniInstance;


    MyClassWrapper(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        instantiate(arg1, arg2, arg3);
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() {
        release();
    }

    private native void instantiate(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3);
    public native void release();
    public native int process(short[] data);

}
```

C++

```
void MyClass::process(const short *data) {
      . . . 
}

MyClass* MyClass::fromJava(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    return obj == nullptr ? nullptr
            : (MyClass *) env->GetLongField(obj, env->GetFieldID(env->GetObjectClass(obj), "jniInstance", "J"));

//============================================================

extern "C" JNIEXPORT JNICALL void
Java_myapp_mypackage_MyClassWrapper_instantiate(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jint arg1, jint arg2, jint arg3) {
    env->SetLongField(thiz,
           env->GetFieldID(env->GetObjectClass(thiz), "jniInstance", "J"), 
           (jlong)new MyClass(arg1, arg2, arg3) );
}

extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_myapp_mypackage_MyClassWrapper_release(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
    jfieldID  fldId = env->GetFieldID(env->GetObjectClass(thiz), "jniInstance", "J");
    MyClass *instance = (MyClass *) env->GetLongField(thiz, fldId);
    if (instance != nullptr) {
        delete instance;
        env->SetLongField(thiz, fldId, (jlong) nullptr);
    }
}


extern "C" JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL
Java_myapp_mypackage_MyClassWrapper_process(
        JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jshortArray jdata) {

    jshort *data = env->GetShortArrayElements(jdata, nullptr); 
    MyClass *instance = MyClass::fromJava(env, thiz);
    instance->process(data);
    env->ReleaseShortArrayElements(jboard, data, JNI_ABORT);
}
```

Works OK. However converting reference to long and long back to reference look a bit awkward to me, while using `long` with a 32-bit CPU (most of Android phones are like that) is really bizaire.

Is there a more appropriate way?

Comment: No, a `jlong` is the recommended type for storing an address.

Comment: Also, a Java `long` (and a native `jlong`) is always 64 bits in size, in case you were worried about the address not fitting.

Comment: As far as the _"most Android phones are [32-bit devices]"_ claim is concerned: most mid- and high-end Android phones released in the last 5 years have been ARM64-based. For example, the last Samsung flagship device to use an ARMv7 platform was AFAIK the Galaxy S5.

Comment: Michael: I just meant that converting from long to int and vice versa is a waste of time and space.